# Javascript modified array before group by

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

i am trying to modified array before groupBy

i have this array

```
[
    {
        name: 'BoxOne',
        count: 3
    },
    {
        name: 'BoxTwo',
        count: 2
    },
]
```

i am trying to modified as per count value has in object value **count 3 + 2 = 5** object should in array

witch function i use ? for output array like this

```
[
    {
        name: 'BoxOne',
        count: 3
    },
    {
        name: 'BoxOne',
        count: 3
    },
    {
        name: 'BoxOne',
        count: 3
    },
    {
        name: 'BoxTwo',
        count: 2
    },
    {
        name: 'BoxTwo',
        count: 2
    },
]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
let newArr = yourArr.reduce((arr, item) => {
  for (let i = 0; i < item.count; i++) {
      arr.push(item);
  }
  return arr;
}, []);

console.log(newArr);
```

you can use reduce array's function. And make iterating by count inside it

or if you need create new objects try spread syntax

```
let newArr = yourArr.reduce((arr, item) => {
  for (let i = 0; i < item.count; i++) {
      arr.push({...item});
  }
  return arr;
}, []);

console.log(newArr);
```

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you want to build a new array based on the contents of an existing one. For this, I would turn to Array.reduce(). For example:

```
const input = [
  {
    name: 'BoxOne',
    count: 3
  },
  {
    name: 'BoxTwo',
    count: 2
  },
];

const output = input.reduce((boxes, box) => {
  const { count = 0 } = box;

  for (let i = 0; i < count; i++) {
    boxes.push(box);
  }

  return boxes;
}, []);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can iterate and flatten the `before` array with `Array.flatMap()`, and generate an array of items according to `count` using `Array.from()`.

Note: You need to shallow clone the objects, if you don't want multiple references to the same object. This prevent all connected "objects" from changing, when one of them is changed.

```js
const before = [{"name":"BoxOne","count":3},{"name":"BoxTwo","count":2}]

const after = before.flatMap(o => 
  Array.from({ length: o.count }, () => ({ ...o }))
)

console.log(after)
```

Answer (score 0):

If your intention is to clone the object in the array the number of times the count inside it, here is the solution.

```
let boxes = [
    {
        name: 'BoxOne',
        count: 3
    },
    {
        name: 'BoxTwo',
        count: 2
    },
]

let newBoxes = [];

boxes.forEach(box => 
 {
   let count = box.count; 
    while(count > 0)
    {
      newBoxes.push(box); 
      count--;
     }
    }
);
```

Your `newBoxes` will have the expected output.

```
[
    {
        name: 'BoxOne',
        count: 3
    },
    {
        name: 'BoxOne',
        count: 3
    },
    {
        name: 'BoxOne',
        count: 3
    },
    {
        name: 'BoxTwo',
        count: 2
    },
    {
        name: 'BoxTwo',
        count: 2
    },
]
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a more concise way to use `.reduce()`.

```js
const boxes = [{"name":"BoxOne","count":3},{"name":"BoxTwo","count":2}]

const newBoxes = boxes.reduce((acc, o) => 
  [...acc, ...new Array(o.count).fill(o)]
, [])

console.log(JSON.stringify(newBoxes, null, 2))
```

It assumes you don't mind using the same object reference.

It uses spread syntax to always fill the return value with the current content of the accumulator, and the content of a new array containing the desired number of objects for the current iteration, using `.fill()`.